# How can I run a Svelte/Sapper app over HTTPS/SSL?

Tags: ssl, https, svelte, sapper

I can't seem to find anything about running Svelte apps over https. I would like to run on https for both dev and prod. I am able to change the port with `--port` argument in the scripts in package.json, but obviously that doesn't change the protocol from http to https.

Comment: There is a solution here using [Devilbox](https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox/issues/709) and the default [Svelte template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create SSL certificates from somewhere(like [ZeroSSL](https://zerossl.com/)). If you already have got `certificate.crt` & `private.key` files, then edit your `server.js` file.

The original source codes of `<sapper project directory>/src/server.js` are:

```js
import sirv from 'sirv';
import polka from 'polka';
import compression from 'compression';
import * as sapper from '@sapper/server';

const { PORT, NODE_ENV } = process.env;
const dev = NODE_ENV === 'development';

polka() // You can also use Express
    .use(
        compression({ threshold: 0 }),
        sirv('static', { dev }),
        sapper.middleware()
    )
    .listen(PORT, err => {
        if (err) console.log('error', err);
    });
```

You can add & change some codes of this file(`server.js`) like this:

```js
import sirv from 'sirv';
import polka from 'polka';
import compression from 'compression';
import * as sapper from '@sapper/server';

const { PORT, NODE_ENV } = process.env;
const dev = NODE_ENV === 'development';

const { createServer } = require('https');
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
const ssl_port = 443;

const options = {
  // The path & file names could be different.
  key: readFileSync('/home/ubuntu/ssl/private.key'),
  cert: readFileSync('/home/ubuntu/ssl/certificate.crt')
};

const { handler } = polka()
    .use(
        compression({ threshold: 0 }),
        sirv('static', { dev }),
        sapper.middleware()
    )
    .get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.end(`POLKA: Hello from ${req.pathname}`);
    });

// Mount Polka to HTTPS server
createServer(options, handler).listen(ssl_port, _ => {
    console.log(`> Running on https://localhost:${ssl_port}`);
});
```

The added codes are:

```js
const { createServer } = require('https');
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
const ssl_port = 443;

const options = {
  // The path & file names could be different.
  key: readFileSync('/home/ubuntu/ssl/private.key'),
  cert: readFileSync('/home/ubuntu/ssl/certificate.crt')
};
```

The changed codes are:

```js
const { handler } = polka()
    .use(
        compression({ threshold: 0 }),
        sirv('static', { dev }),
        sapper.middleware()
    )
    .get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.end(`POLKA: Hello from ${req.pathname}`);
    });

// Mount Polka to HTTPS server
createServer(options, handler).listen(ssl_port, _ => {
    console.log(`> Running on https://localhost:${ssl_port}`);
});
```

And then you have to run your Svelte/Sapper apps with `sudo` because of the permission of port 443. (like this: `sudo npm run dev` or `sudo npm run start`)

After you run `sudo npm run dev`, you may see the messages:

```sh
$ sudo npm run dev

> TODO@0.0.1 dev /home/ubuntu/ensayar-sapper
> sapper dev

✔ server (2.1s)
✔ client (2.1s)
> Running on https://localhost:443
✔ service worker (42ms)
> Server is not listening on port 3000
```

You can ignore the message `Server is not listening on port 3000`.

Comment: Related for devs using [Devilbox](https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox/issues/709). Thank you for pointing this out! I am going through how to get things right with the default [Svelte Template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template) as well as with [Svelte HMR](https://github.com/rixo/svelte-hmr). Otherwise if you would not mind adding the code for those templates you know what to do. ;)

Comment: Wow, hell of a complete answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This has noting to do with sapper. Just use the options of your server framework. Do you use express or polka? Follow their instructions!

Comment: More-mature frameworks like React and Angular support running dev mode with SSL/HTTPS out of the box. It seems Svelte isn't there yet (or should I say sirv-cli). 

You're absolutely right, for prod we can use Express, Polka, etc.

Comment: @jspinella, I love to use tools that are focusing on their goal. I never use https in dev mode and in production it's highly recommended to use a reverse proxy which cares for all the security stuff.

Answer (score -2):

It seems the only way to do it as of now is to run a reverse proxy (like nginx) in front of the Svelte/Sapper app.

E: sorry... this was the only answer for a while. Do I delete this or what?

Comment: ofc it is possible to use Sapper over https. Sapper uses Express middleware which has many options

Comment: "he answered his own question with the best knowledge he had at the time, let's get him!"

Comment: "he made up something that was the first thing he came across and posted it for all to get wrong direction, yes let's get him"

Comment: You sound like a fascinating person and I would like to get to know you better, add me on LinkedIn?